# How to change the server response header in asp.net2.0 with IIS6.0 server

Tags: asp.net

How to modify the server values of response header through code behind using asp.net 2.0 with IIS6.0 server.

I have tried `Response.Headers.Set("XYZ","ABC");`
But it displays throw integrated pipeline error.

Comment: I have to modify the server value in the respose header......

Comment: Can you post the complete error message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
HttpResponse response = ...;
response.ClearHeaders(); 
response.ClearContent(); 
response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"; 
response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", ""); //(write whatever headers you want like this)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the below in Global.asax.cs to remove the Server header

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
{
    Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
}
```